# Mechanize fill out textarea within <noscript> tag

Tags: python, mechanize

So I have the following HTML code:

```
<form action="blabla" blabla >
<input 1 type=blah>
<input 2 type=blah2> etc
<noscript>
    <textarea name="prda" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
</noscript>
```

I want to fill out that textarea preferrably with mechanize (in Python), however, form["prda"] is always giving me control not found error. Another user on StackOverflow has suggested that mechanize cannot parse controls that are within  tag, which seems kind of odd for me.

Anyway, my question is can mechanize parse the control within  tag and if so, how? Also, if someone can give me the alternative of writing to the textarea, I'd be more than happy to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: I might have found a working solution for you...

Comment: @Deusdies I up voted to fix your reputation

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize can't recognize this particular control, so you need to add a new parameter to your form.

```
br.form.new_control('text','prda',{'value':''})
br.form.fixup()
br.form['prda'] = 'input'
```

I know that probably you're no more interested but I got crazy to solve this same problem.

Comment: Gawd, I wish mechanize had better docs. I had no idea about the `new_control` and `fixup` methods! This is a very old problem and I eventually managed to solve it using `RobustFactory()`, but thanks nonetheless!

Answer (score -2):

I changed your HTMl slightly (closing the "form" tag and adding some content to the text box for testing):

`<form action="blabla" blabla >
        <input 1 type=blah>
        <input 2 type=blah2>
        <noscript>
            <textarea name="prda" rows="3" cols="40">Foobar</textarea>
        </noscript>
    </form>`

Okay, here come the mechanize version:

```
from mechanize import ParseResponse, urlopen

response = urlopen("http://localhost:8000/test")
forms = ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)
form = forms[0]
print form["prda"]
```

This prints "Foobar" so I guess I was successful selecting the textbox.

Non-mechanize version: From [here](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#forms):

```
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
form_page = fromstring(html_code)
form = form_page.forms[0]
form.fields = dict(
    prda='input',
    )
print tostring(form)
```

Comment: I was talking to the person down-voting my mechanize-alternative. Anyway, did you tried my approach?